# Download data from rnoaa (error in API key)

Tags: r, database, time, download, rnoaa

I am trying to download data from NOAA using the rnoaa package of R.

I am using `ncdc_stations` function to download some data:

```
siteNumber <- "GHCND:USC00023505"
metadata_station <- ncdc_stations(datasetid='GHCND', stationid=siteNumber)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in check_response(ncdc_GET(path, args, token, ...)) : 
  x$response_headers$`content-type` == "application/json;charset=UTF-8" is not TRUE
```

Someone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you also cross-post this to the github site for the package? https://github.com/ropensci/rnoaa/issues/390. The author made an update to the code based on that bug report. You'll have to reinstall the latest version of the package from the github site using: `remotes::install_github("ropensci/rnoaa")` You'll need a version >= 1.3.2.95

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you, the issue has been solved!